# Find difference between numbers that are represented in String

Tags: node.js, type-conversion

I have two `String` values that carries a value. how to find the difference between them?

Ex;

```
let _value_h = '119/4';
let _value_l = '25/1';
```

This might be very basic, but, how can we convert the String to `Number`?

Comment: Is a single division the only case to handle, or could you also have other arithmetic operators there?

Comment: it will come only with division. but, i feel, it's good to check for that, to avoid any unwanted errors in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your values are formulae, eval them to get the values first:

```js
let _value_h = '119/4';
let _value_l = '25/1';
eval(`v1 = ${_value_h}`)
eval(`v2 = ${_value_l}`)

// Get the diff
console.log(v1-v2) // High minus low?
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval()` is the "right" way to do this, to cover other arithmetic operators besides division.  Going by your comment, which assumes that you would only have a single division, we can try:

```js
let _value_h = '119/4';
let parts = _value_h.split('/');
let result = parts[0] / parts[1];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let _value_h = '119/4';
let _value_l = '25/1';
let h_dividend = parseInt(_value_h.substring(0,_value_h.indexOf('/')))
let h_divisor = parseInt(_value_h.substring(_value_h.indexOf('/')+1,_value_h.length))
let l_dividend = parseInt(_value_l.substring(0,_value_l.indexOf('/')))
let l_divisor = parseInt(_value_l.substring(_value_l.indexOf('/')+1,_value_l.length))
let h = h_dividend/h_divisor
let l = l_dividend/l_divisor
//if you want value h - value l
console.log(h-l)
//if you want value l - value h
console.log(l-h)
```